# Can't scroll down to view other contents of my html file

Tags: html, css

I am building my own personal website. But at the beginning I got stuck in this problem "Can't scroll down to view other contents."

My html code is:

```html
<main>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-title">
      <h1>HAMID AYUB</h1>
      <span>Software Engineer</span><br>
      <span>Student at NUST, Islamabad</span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="project-section">
    <div class="project-title">
      <h3>PROJECTS</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="project-block">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

And CSS code is:

```css
main .home-section{
  background-color: var(--yellow);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

main .home-section .home-title{
  padding-top: 10rem;
}

main .home-section .home-title span{
 font-family: var(--mulish);
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
 font-weight: lighter;
}  

main .project-section{
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: var(--parrot);
}

main .project-section h3{
  color: var(--black)
}
```

When I run this code, only the `home-section` is displayed on the screen but `project-section` is not being displayed.

Kindly help me out in finding the problem in this code.

Comment: As you can see in [this pen](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/NWNoYXB) This code does not reproduce the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: As @Laif says, your code is actually working for me in the latest version of Chrome.  What browser are you using?  Is it possible it's old enough to fail on the custom properties (CSS variables) or the viewport units?

Comment: Oh I got the mistake...    Actually I didn't upload the whole code assuming the error is in this code but the issue is in "
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}"  
Actually I have to replace overflow with overflow-x

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to when there is some content inside  "project-section" .You can see it with valid background varible and without that you can scroll down with much more height than 10vh.

```html
<html>

<body>
<style>
main .home-section{
  background-color: var(--yellow);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

main .home-section .home-title{
  padding-top: 10rem;
}

main .home-section .home-title span{
 font-family: var(--mulish);
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
 font-weight: lighter;
}  

main .project-section{
  height:100vh;
background:gray;
}

main .project-section h3{
  color: var(--black)
}
</style>

<main>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-title">
      <h1>HAMID AYUB</h1>
      <span>Software Engineer</span><br>
      <span>Student at NUST, Islamabad</span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="project-section">
    <div class="project-title">
      <h3>PROJECTS</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="project-block">
       

          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I feel like the asker would've seen the word "PROJECTS" already if they could scroll at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
main .project-section{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--parrot);
}
```

use position **

```css
main .home-section{
  background-color: var(--yellow);
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

main .home-section .home-title{
  padding-top: 10rem;
}

main .home-section .home-title span{
 font-family: var(--mulish);
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
 font-weight: lighter;
}  

main .project-section{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--parrot);
}

main .project-section h3{
  color: var(--black)
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="home-title">
      <h1>HAMID AYUB</h1>
      <span>Software Engineer</span><br>
      <span>Student at NUST, Islamabad</span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="project-section">
    <div class="project-title">
      <h3>PROJECTS</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="project-block">
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

**